# Rear or Front Facing Camera through EXIF Data?

Tags: applications, camera, exif

I am creating an app that separates selfies from picture taken with the rear-facing camera. I am not doing this 'in real-time' so I started looking at the EXIF data.

I have compared the standard EXIF data from a picture taken with the rear camera and another taken with the front camera, and the same fields appear in both files and no big difference jump out.

Is there a flag in the file or something similar in the EXIF data between rear and front pictures that could positively determine which camera took the picture?